# CheckedListBox and EventArgs

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

What am I doing wrong here? be gentle.

For `CheckedListBox`, I can update the items simply by using:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox4.Items.Add("whatever"); //or use an object
}
```

works great, but what I want to do is send the `CheckedListItem` a set of items from  method within another class

So, I set up another `class something:form1` that has a delegate that points to a method that I call\invoke

The delegate calls\invokes this way:

```
public delegate void m_del(List<DirectoryInfo> ww, string rr);
```

somewhere else in the code:

```
m_del methtouse = new m_del(listme)  

public void listme(List<DirectoryInfo> fi, string mypath) 
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo j in fi)
    {
        mypath = null; //mypath used by another method
        try
        {
            NewCheckboxListItem cb1 = new NewCheckboxListItem();
            cb1.Tag = j.Name;
            cb1.Text = j.Name;
            checkedListBox4.Items.Add(cb1);
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(w.Message);
        }
    }
 }                        

 public class NewCheckboxListItem
 {
     // define a text and
     // a tag value

     public string Text;
     public string Tag;

     // override ToString(); this
     // is what the checkbox control
     // displays as text
     public override string ToString()
     {
         return this.Text;
     }
 }

 methtouse( a List<DirectoryInfo> ww, a string rr)
 {}
```

What happens is the Item collection in the `checkedListBox4` is updated and has as many value as i send it, but it will not draw the item\show the item

I have tried calling a `checkedListBox4_datavaluememberchanged` method  and a few other `checkedListBox4_changed` events but once again the items in the collection are updated but they do not appear in the `CheckedListBox`

I think its something to do with it not having `eventargs`

Is there an easy way to do a side by side comparison of ALL the attributes, events, properties of a successful `CheckedListBox` with that of an unsuccessful `CheckedListBox` (programmatically)

**Note:** The class inherits from `form1` where the `CheckedListBox` is located, and the methods access is set to public.

Comment: Add "this.Show()" to the bottom of the method.  Do you see it now?

Comment: thanks but same issue - data appears in the inner array but not the screen --- thanks for try to help mt though

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is to tell the checkedListBox what the value is supposed to be for that object.

```
checkedListBox4.ValueMember = "Text";
```

That tells the CheckedListBox to use the member matching that exact string as the display value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023338/455536

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yx132k0(v=vs.110).aspx

> A string that specifies the property of the data source from which to draw the value.