# How to create a Winforms Combobox with Label and Value?

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox

I am mostly an ASP.NET developer but I am working on a WinForms app and noticed a large difference between the ASP.NET combobox (html select) and that of WinForms.  I found (maybe incorrectly so) that WinForm's combobox only has a "label" whereas ASP.NET allows you to specify a "label" and a "value".

I am looking to use a WinForms combobox (or another comparable control) with a label and a value (Foobar / 42329).  Is this possible?  I have attempted to search for the answer but haven't come up with much.  If there is no way to accomplish that, how does one go ahead and design a WinForm combobox that would represent say Cities with their associated database id?

- Toronto / 2324
- Montreal / 64547
- Vancouver / 1213

Comment: If you are not using binding you could use this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319946, otherwise use Marcs answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I can think of a few ways:

- override the `ToString()` of a `City` class to `return Name + " / " + Id;`
- ditto, but with a `TypeConverter`
- add a `DisplayText` property that return the same, and use `DisplayMember`
- build a shim class for the data

For the last:

```
var data = cities.Select(city => new {
     Id = city.Id, Text = city.Name + " / " + city.Id }).ToList();
cbo.ValueMember = "Id";
cbo.DisplayMember = "Text";
cbo.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: I had no idea the combobox was so powerful... I utilized this solution as I am a Linq newb as well and decided to go down this road.  Stackoverflow rules, thanks guys!

Comment: Seems a bit trivial, but "Id = city.Id" can be simplified down to just "city.Id" as .Net will use the name of the property setter if none is specified.

Comment: @Arbiter yes, I know; I just like to be explicit ... avoids surprises when I rename things ;p

Comment: Trivial comment, but I've just been bitten - the .ToList() part is important, otherwise the assignment to DataSource fails at run-time.

Answer (score 41):

Assuming that your values are unique, you can first populate a dictionary then bind the combobox to the dictionary. Unfortunately databinding requires an IList or an IListSource so you have to wrap it in Binding Source. I found the solution [here](http://madprops.org/blog/Bind-a-ComboBox-to-a-generic-Dictionary/).

```
    private void PopulateComboBox()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Add(2324, "Toronto");
        dict.Add(64547, "Vancouver");
        dict.Add(42329, "Foobar");

        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    }
```

Comment: Hi how do you do this in VB, I have no error in compile time but I have error in runtime

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember need to be assigned BEFORE DataSource is defined

Comment: @CJxD No the don't, at least nit in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 7):

You could try creating a small class called `ComboBoxItem`, like so:

```
public class ComboBoxItem<T>
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Label ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And then when you need to get an object, just cast it to a `ComboBoxItem`.

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString` on a string?

Comment: He's overriding "ToString" so that it's never null.

Answer (score 5):

A ComboBox can be bound to a collection of objects by setting its [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property.

By default, the SelectedValue property will be give the object that was selected, and the list will call `ToString` on each object and display the result.
However, if you set the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property of the ComboBox, it will  display the value of the property named in DisplayMember in the list.  Similarly, you can set the [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) property of the ComboBox and the SelectedValue proeprty will return the value of the property named by ValueMember.

---

Therefore, you need to bind the ComboBox to a list of objects that have `Name` and `Value` properties.
You can then set the ComboBox's [`DisplayMember` property to `Name` and `ValueMember` property to `Value`.

**EDIT**: You can also call the `Add` method and give it such an object instead of databinding.  Alternatively, you could bind it to a `List<T>` or an array.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without databinding?  I am manually adding items to the combobox.

Comment: If you set the ValueMember / DisplayMember properties of the combobox you do not need to databind.  It will should use them even if you use the combobox.Add(yourobject);  The catch is that you still need a name/value object.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called `DisplayMember` = name of property whose value will be used for display, and `ValueMember` which is the property of the to use for the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
        anestezi.DisplayMember = "Text";
        anestezi.ValueMember = "Value";
        anestezi.DataSource = new[] { 
            new { Text = "Genel", Value = "G" }, 
            new { Text = "Lokal", Value = "L" },
            new { Text = "Sedasyon", Value = "S" }
        };
        anestezi.SelectedIndex = 0;
```