# How to update a Label's text when changing the SelectedIndex property of a ComboBox control?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, label, selectedindexchanged

What I want to do here is that for every new item added into the `ComboBox`, a Label's text property will display +1 from the previous number.

How do I write it out, assuming I didn't assign the items a number.

```
Items              Label
Tom                 1
Jane                2
Mary                3
John                4
etc..               etc..
```

Edit: My `ComboBox` is binded to a data source.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim studentcheck = StudentTableAdapter.checkstudent(StudentNameTextBox.Text, StudentAddressTextBox.Text)

    If StudentNameTextBox.Text.Length = 0 Then

        MsgBox("Name is Empty")

    ElseIf StudentAddressTextBox.Text.Length = 0 Then

        MsgBox("Address is empty")

    ElseIf studentcheck Is Nothing Then

        Me.Validate()
        Me.StudentBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LibraryDataSet)
        frmAddLoan.DisplayLoanTableAdapter.Fill(frmAddLoan.LibraryDataSet.DisplayLoan)
        frmAddLoan.ComboBox1.Update()
        MsgBox("Student Info Added")

    Else

        MsgBox("Student Name and Address have been used.")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to display total items count of combobox when new item is added? Provide your code where new item is added to combobox, please..

Comment: I've added in the code on the question

Comment: Or do you want to add the number to the ComboBox itself? But that depends on the sort order of the items (or a Datetime column that indicates the creation-time or the PK column). http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023338/284240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    label1.Text = (ComboBox1.selectedIndex+1).ToString()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
label1.Text = ComboBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: the label only display the total amount of items I have, I have updated my question again.