# C# ComboBox with Text and Value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Winforms Combobox with Label and Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023316/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-with-label-and-value)

How would one approach storing a display value and a real value in a ComboBox?

Ie, the ComboBox displays:

- Destroy World
- Fire Slingshot
- Summon Cthulhu

but the values as retrieved are:

- dw
- ss
- sc

I want to be able to retrieve the value of the selected item in a way similar to this:

```
string selectedValue = combobox1.SelectedValue
```

#### Updated code in response to answers:

```
Dictionary<string, string> filterItems = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Destroy World", "dw"},
    {"Fire Slingshot", "fs"},
    {"Summon Cthulu", "sc"},
};
this.options_filterby.DataSource = new BindingSource(filterItems, null);
this.options_filterby.DisplayMember = "Key";
this.options_filterby.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Now for some reason, although the DisplayMembers are absolutely fine, the ValueMembers return dictionary objects. Even stranger, after a while, eventually the ValueMembers will return strings as expected.

```
private void options_filterby_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(options_filterby.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

This returns dictionaries for the first few times I change the selected item of the ComboBox, but eventually returns strings as needed.

#### Update: fixed (can't add as solution because question was closed)

In response to the above problem, the fix is to set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties *before* the DataSource. I presume this is a bug.
The code should read:

```
this.options_filterby.DisplayMember = "Key";
this.options_filterby.ValueMember = "Value";
this.options_filterby.DataSource = new BindingSource(filterItems, null);
```

Comment: WinForms, WPF, Silverlight or ASP.NET?

Comment: Can you post the code sample?

Comment: Visual Studio .NET forms

Comment: How do you know that the following: `Destroy`, `SlingShot`, and `Cthulhu`, will be retrieved? I measn what's your basis? Your question is too unclear.

Comment: The dictionary answer in the link is what I needed, thanks.

Comment: Even though this is labeled a duplicate, I like the fix in your question better. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to determine what the ComboBox will display, and what will be returned from `SelectedValue`. When you set the `DataSource` property, the ComboBox will use the property described by `DisplayMember` to render a string to the user.

- [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f.aspx)
- [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx)
- [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx)

---

Something like this

```
public class Item {
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Value { get; set; }
}

ComboBox box = new ComboBox();
box.DisplayMember = "Name";
box.ValueMember = "Value";
box.DataSource = new [] { new Item() { "Test", "test" } };
```

If you don't set `ValueMember` the actual Item is returned instead, and if you don't set `DisplayMember`, the items `ToString()` method will be used to get the string presented to the user.

---

I'm not sure if this will work or if it may change what you have, but you could try it at least :)
The thing is, I'm not certain what BindingSource does when it gets a dictionary as its datasource. I suppose it treats it as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` though, so your code should work, but well, it doesn't, so perhaps this will..

```
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in filterItems) {
    source.Add(pair);
}
options_filterby = source;
```

Comment: The answer I'm using (similar to yours) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023316/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-with-label-and-value
Is doing some weird things. The ComboBox displays fine with the right items, but for the first 3 times I use box.SelectedValue in the SelectedIndexChanged event, it returns a dictionary object before finally returning just the Value part of the dictionary. Any ideas?

Comment: @CJxD: SelectedValue can not return a dictionary and *then* return a value. Can you clarify what you mean with that statement? Also, can you provide some information (perhaps edit your question) to include how you are setting up the DataSource collection?

Comment: Basically it cures itself after a few seconds. Is there a delay for setting box.ValueMember or something?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to populate the combo box, and also the code called by the SelectedIndexChanged handler?

Comment: @CJxD: Please see my edit to try!

Comment: @Patrick See the rest of the question, I found how out to fix the problem =]

Comment: @CJxD Oh, good find! I'm glad it worked out

Answer (score 9):

The ComboBox.Items collection stores values of type *object*.  So it can store any kind of type you desire.  It generates the *display* value from the object's ToString() method.  To obtain the *real* value, simply cast the object to the type of your class.