# How can i change the Name that is Displayed in the Combobox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I am building a Studentlist and don't know how to overcome a problem. I am using a Combobox to display all the Students that have been created. I save the Students directly into the Combobox using this code:

```
private void btnSpeichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student StudentSave = new Student
            {
                ID = txtStudentID.Text,
                FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                LastName = txtLastName.Text,
                Age = nudAge.Value,
                Height = nudHeight.Value,
                Schoolclass = txtSchoolClass.Text,
                Gender = cbxGender.Text,
            };

            cbxStudentIDs.Items.Add(StudentSave);
        }
```

cbxStudentIDs stands for the Combobox. I would like to have the Student ID as the name that is displayed, but It shows "WindowsFormsApp2.Form1+Student" for every Student I save.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 C#. Thanks for any helpful advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# ComboBox with Text and Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062810/c-sharp-combobox-with-text-and-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could begin by declaring a property of `BindingList<Student>`. For example,

```
BindingList<Student> StudentCollection = new BindingList<Student>();
```

You could then bind this list to the ComboBox using the following.

```
cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = StudentCollection;
cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "ID";
```

The `DisplayMember` ensures that the ID property of Student is used as Display String for ComboBox.

You could now continue adding the Student to the newly created Collection as

```
Student StudentSave = new Student
            {
                ID = txtStudentID.Text,
                FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                LastName = txtLastName.Text,
                Age = nudAge.Value,
                Height = nudHeight.Value,
                Schoolclass = txtSchoolClass.Text,
                Gender = cbxGender.Text,
            };
 StudentCollection.Add(StudentSave);
```

[`BindingList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8) supports two-way databinding.This would ensure each time you add a new item to your collection (`StudentCollection`), the ComboBox would be refreshed accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! That is really helpful :) I'll test it first thing tomorrow morning and let you know how it went! Also, do you know if there is a way to save new Students without a Database? I have no idea how to use one and would like to keep it a s simple as possible. Thanks again 

Comment: Hey again, so the name is displayed perfectly now. However, everytime I enter a ID the previous ones gets removed. Is there any way to keep them at all?

Comment: @DennisScheurer Believe you are adding to existing collection and not reassigning the collection ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add the whole object to the combobox, just a list of IDs. So you would change `cbxStudentIDs.Items.Add(StudentSave);` to `cbxStudentIDs.Items.Add(StudentSave.ID);`

You would then have to keep the actual state of the student object elsewhere that you can link to it using the ID, whether that is a database or an in memory collection is up to you.

Alternatively, you can link a data source with the student data in as a source for the combobox and set the `DisplayMember` as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/create-a-lookup-table-for-a-wf-combobox-listbox)