# How do I set values for the entries in a Windows Forms ComboBox?

Tags: winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I want to have a drop down list with 12 choices.

I found that ComboBox is what I need (if there is a better control kindly tell me).

I dragged and drop a combo box into a panel using VS2012 and then clicked on the left arrow that appears on the combo box. The following wizard shows:

[image]

As you can see, I am just able to type the name of the choice but not the value of it.

*My question is how to get the value of these choices?*

#### What I have tried

I built an array with the same length as the choices, so when the user selects any choice, I get the position of that choice and get the value from that array.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Is this connected to a dataset? What do you mean by values? Is the `DisplayMember` not the value? -Is it an ID from a database you want to be the value?

Comment: @KidCode no it is not connected to any data source, these are just a static choices and will never change

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Winforms Combobox with Label and Value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023316/how-to-create-a-winforms-combobox-with-label-and-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a datatable and then select the value from that.
eg)

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);
        //Setting Values
        combobox.ValueMember = "ID";
        combobox.DisplayMember = "Description";
        combobox.SelectedValue = "ID";
        combobox.DataSource = dt;
```

You can then populate your datatable using:

```
 dt.Rows.Add("1","ComboxDisplay");
```

Here, the DisplayMember(The dropdown list items) are the `Descriptions` and the Value is the `ID`.

You need to include a 'SelectedIndexChanged' Event on your combobox (If using VS then double click the control in Design Mode) to get the new values. Something like:

```
 private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = Combobox.ValueMember;
        string Description = ComboBox.DisplayMember.ToString();

    }
```

You can then use the variables in the rest of your code.

Comment: I noticed a few inconsistencies in the code I posted, I've edited my answer to make it easier for you to follow!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the wizard to store values and text. To store DisplayText/Value pair the combobox needs to be connected to some data.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }            
}
```

There are two properties on the combobox - DisplayMember and ValueMember. We use these to tell the combobox that - show whats in DisplayMember and the actual value is in ValueMember.

```
private void DataBind()
{
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.DisplayText = "Item1";
    item.Value = 1;

    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);       
}
```

To get the value -

```
 int selectedValue = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: `comboxBox1.DisplayMember` must be a list not a string right?

Comment: DisplayMember is the NAME of the property on the source that should be displayed.

Comment: I got this exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line `int selectedValue = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;`

Comment: +1 for your efforts, but the other answer help me better. thanks