# Assign a label and a value to each element of a combobox (c# - winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, multivalue

[c#]

After reading data in a database, I want to insert in the combobox and assign one value for any insert.

Example: 
[data_read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tINaj.png)

I ***haven't*** a problem to insert a surname in combobox. 
But I have a problem to assign in surname1 at id 1...surname2 at id 12 etc... 
I need to assign the value that I read from the query
and not assign with an `if` or `case` statement.

It's possible to assign label (that is 'surname') and value (that is 'id') for any item of combobox?!

*and*

it's possible to not see the 'id' in combobox ?

In a nutshell, I can do something similar to HTML option value, where for each label (via fogazzaro, via roma etc... we have an associated value).

```
<select name="sedi">
  <option value="1">Via fogazzaro</option>
  <option value="22">Via roma</option>
  <option value="38">Via Olevano</option>
  <option value="42">Via Mazzini</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for bad english.

I hope that you have understood me.

Good code for all! :)

Comment: You should at least tell us the GUI framework you use - WinForms, WPF, UWP, WebForms...?

Comment: sorry, sorry.... Windows Form!

Comment: Then edit your question by including the [winforms] tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Winforms Combobox with Label and Value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023316/how-to-create-a-winforms-combobox-with-label-and-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this is creating a class with two fields, *ID* and *Surname*. Then use the `SelectedIndex` property to resolve the user's selection to an index in a collection:

```
class Person
{
    ID { get; set }
    Surname { get; set; }      
}
```

Place collection of `Person` objects into a `List` (likely a real-world example would read from database and populate list within a loop):

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() {
    new Person()
    {
        ID = 1,
        Surname = "Smith"
    },
    ...
};
```

Then use the selected index to resolve the `Person` object instance when the user selects an item from the list:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something useful with your object:
    MessageBox.Show(
        "You selected:\n" + 
        people[comboBox.SelectedIndex].ID + "\n" + 
        people[comboBox.SelectedIndex].Surname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to store your data, and override the ToString() method to return the text you wish to see in the combobox.

```
class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Then add objects of this class to the combobox.

```
comboBox.Items.Add(new Item() {ID = 1, Name = "Fred"});
comboBox.Items.Add(new Item() {ID = 2, Name = "Jane"});
```

Then, to access the selected item (in a handler or wherever):

```
Item selected = comboxBox.SelectedItem as Item;

if (selected != null)
{
    // do something with 'selected'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ID's are unique, you could have a dictionary where the key is the ID and the value is the surname. In your combobox add

```
SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

and make the ItemsSource the dictionary. This way the combobox's SelectedItem will be the ID, but the "label" will be the surname